# Error SQL71501: View: [dbo].[View_Engagements] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Engagements]

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

I have create the DB project uisng VS 2017. I have **NOT** added the [dbo].[Engagements] table into this DB project because the [dbo].[Engagements] table is  part of another DB project.
Now I have added the below view and gettign the error as

**Error SQL71501: View: [dbo].[View_Engagements] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Engagements]**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_Engagements]
AS
    SELECT E.Id FROM [dbo].[Engagements] E
GO
```

Now I want to add above view into DB project.

Any help will really appreciated.

Comment: Don't tag spam... SQL Server <> MySQL, and this is *clearly* SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: As for the error, it's telling you the problem. `[dbo].[Engagements]` doesn't exist, so the `VIEW` can't be compiled.

Comment: Try adding a reference to the project that contains the table.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory, you can't reference a non-existent table. This view should be part of the same project?

The workaround, if you really need it, is to create the table, create your view, then drop your table. This will if course invalidate the view, but it should work when the base table is created by the other project.

```
create table Engagements (Id int)
GO

create view View_Engagements....
GO

drop table Engagements
GO
```

Comment: Yes. I want to add the view in the same project. By added create table in the view will not work as you are deleting it... As I said, create table is in another DB project and I can't re-create it or drop it.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the table being anywhere, within the view you need to write the source name :
databasename.schema.tablename and in case of a linked server :
linkedservername.databasename.schema.tablename.
So you would need to update the view script.

In order for your database project to build successfully, you would need to create a reference in database project :
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=a%20composite%20project-,In%20Solution%20Explorer%2C%20right%20click%20References%20and%20select%20Add%20Database,and%20paste%20it%20into%20your%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=a%20composite%20project-,In%20Solution%20Explorer%2C%20right%20click%20References%20and%20select%20Add%20Database,and%20paste%20it%20into%20your%20).

Comment: _databasename.schema.tablename_ Need to? Nope, in fact it is a bad habit.

Comment: Hey @SMor,
Thanks for the input but then how do you suggest the view definition would be in case if I have to reference a table from another database within the same server:
Cross database queries?
Reference : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6445/azure-sql-cross-database-query/